# How is the PHPSESSID generated?

Tags: php

Psudeocode or PHP code desirable. References even better on the components and procedures to generate the PHPSESSID manually.

Comment: Both answers are both good. How do i tick em both! :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The code that generates the sssion ID is [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L315) - but it's C, since that's how PHP itself is implemented.

Basically, it uses a cryptographic hash function and as input the remote IP address, the current time and some other stuff.

The hash function to use and optionally a source of additional entropy can be [configured in php.ini](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function).

Comment: @Tim: Ah, right. I saw some -> in there and wasn't aware that C uses that operator as well.

Comment: +1 for correcting and indicating it can be salted in php.ini :)

Answer (score 6):

It's hashed from the remote address and the current time, in [ext/session/session.c:344(`php_session_create_id()`)](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/session/session.c?view=markup#l344).

Comment: Source moved to [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L315). I don't see it being hashed from the address and time though.

Comment: @SWdV: A lot can change in 7 years.